# Why is jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool() not working as expected?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I've built a client-side custom validation rule that works using unobtrusive validation, which is shown below.

```
$(function () {
    $.validator.addMethod('custom', function (value, element, params) {
        return (value == 47);
    });

    var input = $("#myField");
    input.rules("add", {
        custom: true,
        messages: {
            custom: "The value must be 47"
        }
    });
}); 

<input name="myField" id="myField" type="number" value="">
<span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="myField"></span>
```

However, I then tried to improve the code in order to get it truly "unobtrusive" by doing the following:

```
$(function () {
    $.validator.addMethod('custom', function (value, element, params) {
        return (value == 47);
    });

    $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool('custom');
}); 

<input name="myField" id="myField" type="number" value="" data-val-custom="The value must be 47" data-val="true">
<span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="myField"></span>
```

But the addBool() method doesn't seem to work and doesn't generate an error. What have I missed? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was because the `addBool()` method is called inside a jQuery function.

```
$(function()
{
    //do stuff
})
```

Changing it to a self-invoking function worked, presumably because `addBool()` gets called *before* some code inside of `jQuery.validate.unobtrusive.js` instead of *after*.

```
(function()
{
    //do stuff
})()
```

I'd actually had the opposite problem this morning where the code snippet below had to be in a jQuery function rather than a self-invoking function in order for it to work.

```
    var input = $("#myField");
    input.rules("add", {
        custom: true,
        messages: {
            custom: "The value must be 47"
        }
    });
```